# Бинарные деревья в СИ: Обход узлов заданного уровня

Tags: data-structures, c

Добрый вечер

Есть задание: Посчитать среднее арифметическое элементов дерева заданного уровня. Никак не придет в голову как обойти узлы конкретного уровня (как его определить?)

Вот существующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
       int x;
       Node *left, *right;
};

Node *tree = NULL;

void push( int a, Node**Mytree)
{
     if( (*Mytree) == NULL ){
         (*Mytree) = new Node;
         (*Mytree) -> x = a;
         (*Mytree) -> left = (*Mytree) -> right = NULL;
         return;
     }

     if( a > ( (*Mytree) -> x) ) push( a, &(*Mytree) -> right);
     else push( a, &(*Mytree) -> left);
}

void print (Node *Mytree, int u)
{

      if(Mytree){
      print(Mytree->left, u+1);
      for ( int i = 0; i < u; i++) cout << "   ";
      cout << Mytree -> x<< endl;
      print( Mytree -> right, u+1);
      }

}
int main()
{
     int n,s;
     cout << "VVedite kolichestvo elementov\n";
     cin >> n;

     for ( int i =0; i < n; ++i){
         cout << "Vvedite znachenie elementa\n";
         cin >> s;
         push ( s , &tree);
     }
     cout << "vashe derevo\n";
     print(tree,0);
     getch();
     return 0;
     }
```

Если можно, помогите оформить это отдельной функцией

Comment: вы пишите не на "С" а на "С++" (так как `#include <iostream>` и `using namespace std;`);

что бы вам ни говорили, но это абсолютно разные языки...

Answer (score 1):

есть несколько способов.

1. можно хранить указатель на родителя
       и создать функцию которая будет идти
       от текущей ячейки до корня
       подсчитывая при этом количество
       переходов
2. можно передавать уровень как
       параметр, то есть:

   ```
   print(Node *Mytree, текущий_лвл, нужный_лвл){
       if(текущий_лвл > нужный_лвл) return;

       if(текущий_лвл = нужный_лвл) cout<<*Mytree;

       print(Mytree->left, текущий_лвл+1, нужный_лвл);
       print(Mytree->right,текущий_лвл+1, нужный_лвл);
   }
   ```
3. можно хранить лвл внутри узла